# Using Apache Httpd mod_rewrite to rewrite URL based on Accept request header?

Tags: apache-http-server, url, httpd, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm attempting to rewrite a URL based on the Accept header of the request. I saw in the docs that this seems to be possible, but I couldn't find any details or examples anywhere on how to go about it.

Basically I'd like requests to `/abc/index.html` be rewritten according to the Accept header:

Requests with `Accept: application/vnd.x.v1+json` to be rewritten as `/v1/abc/index.html`
Requests with `Accept: application/vnd.x.v2+json` to be rewritten as `/v2/abc/index.html`

and so forth. And requests with the generic `application/json` Accept header or no Accept header at all to be rewritten as `/v5/abc/index.html`

Any pointers on who I could accomplish this are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^application/vnd\.x\.(v[1-9])\+json
RewriteRule ^(/abc/index\.html)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` line matches the Accept: header and captures the `vX` string.

The RewriteRule does the actual rewriting and prepends the `RewriteCond` captured string to the now captured location; using `%` interpolates `RewriteCond` captures, `$` interpolates RewriteRule captures.

Adjust patterns etc. to suit.

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'll study your example to learn this and derive other uses. Thank you!!